# Can gradient color be used in Email template

Tags: css, background, background-image, linear-gradients, email-templates

Is it possible to use **Gradient color** in Mail Template, without using Background-image.

Comment: https://codepen.io/cstauf2/pen/WQgVXX

Comment: Thanks Brackground image css property works for some